# How much bytes Informatica would read in first iteration

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

This is a question asked for me in an interview.

How much bytes informatica would read in first iteration from source?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, But I would say Inofrmatica does not read data in iterations from any source, but if the intention was to ask how much data would Informatica read before the first commit is done at the target level,  I would say this would depend on the below parameters

1) Line sequential buffer
2) DTM buffer setting
3) Based on the commit point you set i.e. source commit/target commit

If you have set 1000 rows as your commit point, but if the DTM buffer size fills up even before Informatica reads 1000 rows, then obviously this would commit the data.